# summation problem?

Tags: secret-sharing, factoring, threshold-cryptography

Let there are two given numbers $x,y$ which is $A=x+y$ and we know just $A$. How we can find this just $x$ and $y$?

If you suppose $a$ a random number, then we know $x_1=a$ and $y_1=A-a$ satisfies in $A=x_1+y_1$ but with high probability $x_1\neq x$ and so $y_1\neq y$, too. I think this problem is used in some cryptographic protocols like additive secret sharing.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. If you have $A$ from $A = x + y$, you won't be able to find out either $x$ or $y$. You can generate values that would make the equation work, but you couldn't find the originals.

Comment: Yes you are right. I guess it and sounds it is not easy problem but I would like to know really there is no (efficient or not efficient) method or practical algorithm to find original ones. A paper or a discussion or any good reference.

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not possible.

Assuming a finite group, for any $A$ in the group and for any $x$ in the group, the pair $(x,A-x)$ is a possible solution.
You cannot do any better. If you have some side information which enables you test a value $x$ for being valid, you would at worst still need to test every $x$ in the group.

This property follows from the uniqueness of inverses in a group.